# Do we need both the [klingon] and [klingon-language] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just got a [suggested edit](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27) that added the [klingon](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon) tag to a question where I had included the [klingon-language](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon-language) tag. As of right now, [klingon](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon) has one question in it and [klingon-language](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon-language) has two.

These seem... kinda redundant to me; **why do we have both? Which should we use primarily?**

Comment: Does this need a meta post? With so few questions, you could just make edits to uniformise (like I've been editing to remove the [tag:tolkien] tag).

Comment: @Randal'Thor - A meta post will determine which is better and which will be kept.

Comment: The Klingon Tag should be a synonym of Klingon-Language. Or the other way around.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Being a site dedicated to languages, I think the idea of adding [language](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) to the end of a tag is unnecessary.

[klingon-language](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon-language) should be merged into [klingon](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon).

I could see a potential for a tag such as [klingon-alphabet](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon-alphabet), as that's distinct from the language itself, but even that is a stretch and should probably be wrapped under [klingon](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously **we don't need both**, since questions about Klingons or Klingon culture excluding language presumably won't be on-topic here.

However, to make it clear that the tag is only about the Klingon language and not anything else to do with Klingons, I suggest **using [klingon-language](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon-language) as the primary tag name**.

Comment: (I was going to post an answer supporting [tag:klingon] as the master too, for easier voting, but corsiKa beat me to it.)